# Django Error Reverse for 'url' not found. 'url is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, url, reverse

I'm working on Django and in a trouble with removing old urls.
I've got seven pages(urls) in my present program but decided to make it simpler with only three pages(urls).
Then I tried to remove them just by comment-out, but it just comes out with the error like `Reverse for 'url name' not found. 'url name' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`
I'm not getting those unnecessary urls set in other pages, so it should be deleted without any problem.

Here is a snap shot to go more in details.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLlcJ.jpg)

A page link is showing as an error origin, but the page is actually nothing to do with the deleted urls.
Need your help! Thanks!

Comment: Commenting the html doesn't avoid the template tags to be processed. You have to delete the lines or comment them with template comment {# ... #}

Comment: @guillermochamorro
thanks for your comment! I removed them completely but still get the same error...

Answer (score 1):

In your template the named URLs your removed are being referenced. The template tag `url` performs a `reverse` on the URL and is informing you (correctly) that it can't be found.

Where they are referenced in the templates they will need to be removed or commented out with `{# <content to be commented out> #}`. Commenting out the HTML will not be sufficient as it will still get processed by the template engine.

Edit: to clarify where this needs to occur is every template file that is used not the removed templates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! I cleaned those urls completely off the urlpatterns list and deleted html files themselves but still get the same error...should i migrate or something to make this change reflected? sorry for the trouble...

Comment: You will need to remove all the lines where `{% url '<old URL name>' %}` in each of the templates in your project e.g. remove `{% url 'BULMA_ABOUTUS' %}`  from all template files in your project. If that is done has the error changed at all?

Comment: @SonogiYang don't forget to mark the answer as the valid one.